# IE8 rounded corners issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html-components

I've encountered odd problems with rounded corners in IE8. .htc file was used and http://wpdev.net78.net/ looks OK in IE8, however there's a problem with 2 of the corners - 1st is under TEST link and second at the bottom. I've applied the same rules as to the other elements, however this one don't wants to cooperate... Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting just "border-radius: 6px;" or "border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;" on #content-right. It is currently "border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;". Not sure if your .htc file will support this. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

You should switch to PIE.htc (see http://css3pie.com/). It's a newer and much improved alternative to the old HTMLRemix HTC file you're using. It uses the same basic technologies, but more features and better performance. Plus it's under active development, and if there are issues with it, the author is very responsive about dealing with them.

There's a very good change that CSS3Pie will resolve the problems you're having.

If you do still have problems, there are some common issues when dealing with IE with this sort of thing. The biggest one is that in IE elements need to have the "addLayout" flag triggered in order for these HTC programs to work properly. This is an IE-specific glitch; try adding `position:relative;` or `zoom:1;` styles to the affected elements, and see if that helps. The CSS3Pie site has a 'common issues' page which discusses these points in more detail; why the happen and how to deal with them.

Hope that helps.  :)

Comment: Is it just me, or is the latest PIE download EXACTLY the same as the currently available HTMLRemix? They even have the same time-stamp :P

Comment: I think it must be just you. HTML Remix only does border-radius and hasn't been updated since 2009 (download is a 2.5kb HTC file), whereas CSS3Pie does border-radius, gradients and box-shadows, and the most recent update is this month (download is a 110kb zip file, containing a 40kb HTC plus other supporting files). What are you seeing?

Comment: Very weird things. At work I downloaded the PIE-1.0beta5.zip, extracted and saw... exactly the same files when I downloaded and extracted the HTMLRemix ones. But at home just now I see a completely dif. set of PIE files. Thanks for posting and making me re-check... don't quite know what happened at work there o_O