# rounded border problems in IE 8

Tags: css

I am trying to add rounded border to my div. In firefox it is working. On Net i found this link http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser. I have adding the htc file. I included it in the root, as well as my css folder but it is not working on IE. Here what i am doing

```
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
behavior: url(css/border-radius.htc); url(border-radius.htc); //both not working
background: rgb(180,221,180); /* Old browsers */
```

Why it is not working in IE?

Comment: [Bookmark this site](http://caniuse.com/border-radius).

Comment: You can refer this for further clarity.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648359/ie8-rounded-corners-issue

Comment: try css3 pie http://css3pie.com/ but please note you will get a hit i performance and you might get conflicts depending on where the rounded corners are used

Comment: IE8 does not support rounded borders, you can complain to MS :-) Check the link given as duplicate above, and notice the 1st comment (ie, let it go)

Answer (score 2):

> **Rounded corners in IE8**

Internet Explorer under version 9 **doesn't** natively support rounded corners **but** there are few other solutions you may consider:

- Use Rounded Corners **Images** instead ([**this**](http://www.generateit.net/rounded-corner/) is a good resource)
- Use the **jQuery Corner plugin** from [**here**](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner)
- Use a very good script called **CSS3 PIE** from [**here**](http://css3pie.com)
- Another good script is **IE-CSS3** from [**here**](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)

Hope it was useful.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

All IEs <9 don´t support border radius.

Try an border-image generator if it´s really important.

also see @niels post. Try using google for those questions before you go to SO.

Comment: All IEs < 9 don't support border-radius

Comment: =<8 == <9 or am i wrong?

Comment: i´ll edit my post, i think you are right with that...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IE8 doesn't support this css feature.

You could try this trick to go:

[CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: with behaviour file it is possible to get rounded border in IE8 but it reduces performance and causes conflict in css depending on where you are using it

Comment: Sure. It has to be used carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Make the rounded border in photoshop, sketch, or whatever, and set it as background image:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
    #yourid
    {
    background-image: your source
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```